# Amazon S3 PHP SDK pre-signed requests

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to generate a presigned request with the S3 PHP SDK like this:

```
$s3Client = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory([
    'credentials' => new Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials('my-access-code', 'xxx')
]);

$command = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => 'my-bucket-name',
    'Key' => 'awesome-cat-image.png',
]);

$signedUrl = $command->createPresignedUrl('+10 minutes');
```

But when I goto the URL I get an error saying:

```
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>
        The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
    </Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId>xxx</AWSAccessKeyId>
    <StringToSign>GET 1422564095 /my-bucket-name/awesome-cat-image.png</StringToSign>
    <SignatureProvided>xxx</SignatureProvided>
    <StringToSignBytes>
        xxx
    </StringToSignBytes>
    <RequestId>xxx</RequestId>
    <HostId>
        xxx
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

Accessing https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/awesome-cat-image.png works just fine with permissions set to allow non authenticated users.

Comment: have you attempted the second way to build this `url`? if so did you have the same results? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_createPresignedUrl

Answer (score 1):

```
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => 'my-bucket',
    'Key'    => 'testKey'
]);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

// Get the actual presigned-url
$presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

You can find more details here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html